# Any Heuristic Argument that for the distribution of primes $p$, about half of the primes $p$, $u(2$) $=$ $3$ prime chain?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

First define the limited prime chain sequence $u(n)$ where each term is a prime number ($p$ and $q$ are primes):

$$u(n) = p$$

$$u(n-1) = q$$

$p = 1 \pmod q$, $q$ is the largest prime factor of $p-1$.

Additionally:

$u(1) = 2$

$u(2) = 2^{2^n}+1$ (A Fermat Prime)

$u(3) = s$, where $2^{2^n}+1$ is the largest prime factor of $s-1$.

$u(4) = q$, where $s$ is the largest prime factor of $q-1$.

And so on ... ... ...

For any prime $p$, the sequence stops at $u(n) = p$.

I have done a test among the primes less than $1000$, not all the primes have the same number of sequence terms. I have noticed, that observing $u(2)$ for each prime, about half of them $u(2) = 3$, and nearly a third $u(2) = 5$, is this because the second prime is $3$ and the third prime is $5$? If this is true, then about one-seventh of primes $u(2) = 17$. Can anyone support the argument with a heuristic or theory:

Of the infinitely many primes $u(2) = 3$ will tend to occur most than any other Fermat Prime for $u(2) = 2^{2^n}+1$.

Thanks for helping me solve this problem, it is a hard one.

Comment: Your way of writing MathJax code has major flaws.  See my edits to the question. $\qquad$

Comment: And the theoretical explanation? At least my problem is still explained.